# Show a "title" in the cmd.exe title-bar from a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

According to the [Microsoft Documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770297(v=ws.11).aspx), this is the syntax of the `Start` command:

```
start ["<Title>"] [/d <Path>] [/i] [{/min | /max}] [{/separate | /shared}] [{/low | /normal | /high | /realtime | /abovenormal | belownormal}] [/affinity <HexAffinity>] [/wait] [/b {<Command> | <Program>} [<Parameters>]]
```

So I created a batch file "test.bat" with this content:

```
START "My test" /WAIT notepad
```

...to supposedly have the **cmd.exe** console window showing the title "My test" in the title-bar.

However, when executing this .BAT file, the title "My test" is not displayed in the title bar of the console window:

[image]

So I tried this command in the .BAT file:

```
START title "My test" /WAIT notepad
```

However, when executing this .BAT file, the whole command line was displayed in the title-bar of the console window:

[image]

...and notepad was not started.

So how can I display only the "title" in the title-bar of the console window and have the command executed?

OS: Windows 7 x64 SP1

Comment: The `title` in the `start` command reffers to the newly created window, not the current one. Directly use the `title` command.

Comment: What do you mean by "newly created window"? I want to show "My test" in the title-bar of the cmd.exe console window, directly from the batch file.

Comment: The fist line in the output of the `start /?` help states that this command starts a separate window. The `title` in the command is for this new window (if the started program does not sets it own title)

Comment: I don't know what you mean with "separate window". The cmd.exe console window **IS** a new window. The Microsoft documentation clearly says **"<Title>" Specifies the title to display in the Command Prompt window title bar.**

Comment: CMD executes a program via either `CreateProcess` or `ShellExecuteEx`. When it uses `CreateProcess`, the `start` command can set the optional `lpTitle` field of the [`STARTUPINFO`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686331). Most programs, including Notepad, ignore this field. It's intended to set the title of the console window, which is created by the console host process (conhost.exe). The console host in turn loads window-specific options from the registry key "HKCU\Console\<Window Title>".

Comment: I've found the answer to my question by trial and error. Put this in the batch file: 1. Line: **@ECHO OFF**, 2. Line: **title My test**, 3. Line: **@ECHO ON**, 4. Line: **start /WAIT notepad**

Comment: I don't see how it's trial and error. MC ND told you to use the `title` command. It is not a new console window. The `title` command is implemented internally by calling [`SetConsoleTitle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686050), which (in Windows 8+) is implemented by sending the request to the console host process (conhost.exe) via CMD's console connection handle (i.e. a handle for the "Connect" file on the ConDrv device) for its one and only console (i.e. a Windows process can only be attached to one console at a time). In older versions it sends the request via an LPC handle.

Comment: Because you are running `notepad` from a batch file, there is no need to use the `start` command. The batch file will wait until `notepad` is closed before continuing execution. Line 1:`@Echo Off`, Line 2:`Title My test`, Line 3:`Notepad` Line 4:`Timeout 3`. You will notice when running the above 4 line script that the three second `timeout` will begin only after closing `notepad`!

Comment: In general we may use `start` for its other capabilities, i.e. setting the process base priority or CPU affinity; or running an application based on its registered "App Paths" command. In that case we need to add the `/wait` option back to get the normal batch-mode behavior. If we don't need these features, then we don't need `start` at all.

Comment: @user1580348 to format as code put backticks around code `\`like this\``

Answer (score 5):

The `title` command changes inside the window, just put `title` command in the actual file, or if you want some kind of launcher (I don't know why you would want this) then have a bat using `call` to call the other bat (The one that would have the `title` command inside it)

**EDIT:** I found the answer, if you're starting a program (with the command `start "foo\bar\some spaces\path\yourbat.bat`) then the `start` command automatically interperets `foo\bar\some spaces\path\yourbat.bat` to be the title, too, but if you call `start "title" "foo\bar\some spaces\path\yourbat.bat"` then it will run your file AND interpret the first quotation marks to be the title, and the second the path

Answer (score 0):

```
Title "Your needed title should be typed here without quote"
START "" /WAIT notepad
```

// The two quotes after the start command may also have title within it but this will only reflect in the new window which the Start command is expected to start which will then lunch the notepad.

However, for the current window, the first line Title bla... bla...bla.. is what is required.